# What kind of class information is this?

Tags: php, css, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to decode/reverse engineer a wordpress layout. I'm pouring through the CSS files and can't figure out what all this long menu mumbo-jumbo is!

I'm not asking for anyone to go through the code, but give me an idea what I am looking at. These don't seem to be normal css styling elements.

```
<li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-198 current_page_item menu-item-200">
<a href="http://themewich.com/aware/">Home Shuffle</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element can have many class, and the class names are supposed to be space separated.  That's valid class assignment.

Comment: I guess my question is, there are no styling elements in the CSS files which have those attributes such as "menu-item", "menu-item-object-page", etc. I can't seem to figure out where those are coming from.

Comment: You can also embed css within the html.  Check the html file, and also look for any other css linked within that html file.  If you're curious if they actually do something, remove them and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried to 'inspect' the element in firebug and checked there if those classes affect the styling? It's possible that some JavaScript dynamically appends an external stylesheet? Also, it's possible that those classes are not used for styling, but as selectors for JavaScript to add functionality

Comment: @ArgumentNullException Hah, I like that approach. "Rip it out and see if it dies!" I can get behind that. As for the java, yeah, I'm digging through the JavaScripts now to see what I can find out. Thanks guys, probably not much more help you can give so I appreciate it. =)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they are just being used inside js, jquery.

Comment: Those classes are actually being generated by the call to wp_nav_menu. Any calls to that Wordpress function automatically applies a series of classes to list items, whether or not they're actually used.

Answer (score 2):

It is a list item with multiple classes applied to it.